# spring security where data is stored on server

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

after going through some links for spring security I got to know about how it works. Still I am confused about which username and password I should give in spring-security.xml, because I'm working with the `JSON`. All my data is stored on the server. If i am logging in the page,it will check in the server whether that data exists, and if does,then it should proceed.how can i do this with spring security and authentication..?any help for this..? this is my spring-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/signin*" access="isAnonymous()" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

  <form-login
     login-page='/signin'
     default-target-url="/home"
     authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=true" 
     login-processing-url="/security/j_spring_security_check"  
     />
  <logout logout-success-url="/signin" /> 

</http> and may be i have to add some ref in the authentication manager so that it will check the username and password which are present in the remote server..


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="user" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

if some links are there or some info..then please help me for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the server you can config ( if username and passwprd are stored in the database)

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
         SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, CASE ENABLED WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 'ENABLED' 
         FROM TBL_USERS 
         WHERE USERNAME=?;"

       authorities-by-username-query="
        SELECT u.USERNAME, r.ROLENAME 
        FROM TBL_USERS u, TBL_USER_ROLE r
        WHERE u.ID = r.USERID
        AND u.USERNAME=?;"

        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

or

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="admin" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="dba" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_DBA" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

form login

```
<form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

think it could help

Comment: can u tell what should i write in my controller for the authentiation..?give me some hints or links which are useful